# How to make a connect 4 iphone game?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I want to take the next step and make a game, I had Connect4/4 in a Row in mind.

How would I go about with this, I made a pong game from a tutorial and now I want to make something on my own. This type of game doesn't seem that hard to make or perhaps it is?

Anyone got any good advice or some sample code or instructions?

Thanks for all help guys.
David H

Comment: Do you have a more specific question about a particular aspect of this game?  We're not going to write your application for you, but we'd be glad to help with areas you run into trouble with.

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever heard of cocos2d? Its a framework for making 2d games for the iphone.

The community is very helpful, i think it might help you in your aims to 'take the next step'

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org

Comment: I know of cocos2d, will ask there too.

Answer (score 0):

Glad to hear you're interested! The way I went about my first steps of game programming was to learn everything I could about computers/programming in order to make games. If you’re not 14 any more, and thus infinite time no longer is available, I’d recommend you start out with two tutorials, [one](http://icodeblog.com/2010/07/29/iphone-programming-tutorial-local-notifications/) for plain application programming on the platform at hand and [the other](http://maniacdev.com/2010/01/incredible-iphone-game-programming-tutorials-with-video/) for learning more specifically how to make games for that platform.

After that, pick what boilerplate you want/need from the public domain, and set out to produce your completely own thing. And hey, good luck (you’ll need it)!